# Creating new Scala project using SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I can create a sbt project like so:

```
$ mkdir project1
$ cd project1
$ sbt
Loading /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash

> set name := "project1"
[info] Defining *:name
...

> set scalaVersion :="2.10.2"
[info] Defining *:scalaVersion
...

> set version :="1.0"
[info] Defining *:version
...

> session save
[info] Reapplying settings...

> exit
```

This creates `build.sbt` file for the project.

```
$ cat build.sbt 
name := "project1"

scalaVersion :="2.10.2"

version :="1.0"
```

Now is there any command-line for doing the same? Something like:

```
sbt new_project "name" version scala_version
```

**EDIT1**

I figured out another way i.e. create project folder:

```
$ mkdir project1
$ cd project1/
```

Update project details:

```
$ sbt 'set name := "project1"' 'set scalaVersion :="2.10.2"' 'set version :="1.0"' 'session save'
Loading /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Set current project to project1 (in build file:/tmp/scala/project1/)
[info] Defining *:name
[info] The new value will be used by *:description, *:normalizedName and 6 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to project1 (in build file:/tmp/scala/project1/)
[info] Defining *:scalaVersion
[info] The new value will be used by *:allDependencies, *:ivyScala and 10 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to project1 (in build file:/tmp/scala/project1/)
[info] Defining *:version
[info] The new value will be used by *:isSnapshot, *:projectId and 3 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to project1 (in build file:/tmp/scala/project1/)
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to project1 (in build file:/tmp/scala/project1/)
```

We have project generated and settings saved:

```
$ ls
build.sbt  project
$ cat build.sbt 
name := "project1"

scalaVersion :="2.10.2"

version :="1.0"
```

I hope SBT to natively provide functionality like in Maven: `mvn archetype:generate`.

Comment: You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/20362511/1305344.

Comment: I also wonder why nobody mentioned http://typesafe.com/activator

Comment: @JacekLaskowski That question you mentioned is really a curious one and great explanation there :-)

Comment: @tuxdna Did you manage to get some way to create a maven type archetype for sbt?

Comment: @lazywiz Not sure what you mean. Do you want to create mvn archetype projects using `sbt` cli ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [np](https://github.com/softprops/np) plugin for SBT that does something you are looking for. Usage:

```
$ sbt 
$ np name:my-new-project org:org.myproject version:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: np plugin is a great thing. But it doesn't allow me to create my own archetypes. I want to have something like project template (with 10-15% of ready-to-use code, needed to be extended), not empty project. Is it possible?

Answer (score 16):

From sbt 0.13.13 on there's a built in command `new`:

```
sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
```

Answer (score 3):

you may want to check out my project [skeleton](http://github.com/fractal/skeleton)

It can simplify the first steps when you need to get up and running quickly.

Comment: Each time I have to create a project, I will have to follow same set of steps using `skeleton`. I want a simple command line tool. Perhaps you could add a shell script to make it even easier.